# Rails Nested Attributes - URL Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I am working on a small assignment to create posts and divide them by categories. I have everything working but in my index.html I'm getting the following routing errors related to my links.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
undefined method `post_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd3097f0ce0>:0x007fd3097c9370>
```

In posts/index.html.haml I have:

```
    - @category.posts.each do |post|
        %tr
          %td= post.title
          %td= post.description
          %td= post.user_id
          %td= post.category_id
          %td= link_to 'Show', category_post_path //gives first error
          %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_post_path //gives second error
          %td= link_to 'Destroy', post, 
          :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete //gives third error
```

In routes.rb I have:

```
resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end
```

When I run rake routes I get:

```
categories_index  GET    /categories/index(.:format)    categories#index                
category_posts    GET    /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)     posts#index
                  POST   /categories/:category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
new_category_post GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_category_postGET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
category_post     GET    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                  PUT    /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                  DELETE /categories/:category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

There is something wrong in my index that is making the application crash because I can access and see these with no problems:

```
/categories/:category_id/posts/:id (equivalent to show)
/categories/:category_id/posts/:id/edit (equivalent to edit)
```

Can someone please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL helpers need to know which category and post you're interested in so you have to pass the specific category and post objects as parameters to the helpers. I think these should work:

```
      %td= link_to 'Show', category_post_path(@category,post) //gives first error
      %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_post_path(@category,post) //gives second error
```